Visual Studio Setup Project - Application Pinned to Start Menu disappears on update
I have a .NET 6 C# application with a Setup Project created in Visual Studio.
I'm running into a weird issue where, when I deploy an update and users install the update via the MSI, if they had pinned the application to their Start Menu, after the update is done installing, the pinned application is no longer on the Start Menu.
If you pin it to the taskbar, it stays there just fine but for some reason the Start Menu is behaving differently.
The odd thing is, I can create a dummy project and match the settings to my actual project and it keeps the application pinned to the Start Menu so I'm not sure what could be causing the difference.
I also tried creating a new Setup Project from scratch for my actual application where the only things I did was added the Project Outputs and shortcuts to the File System but that still didn't work either.
Any tips or suggestions as to where to look would be appreciated.

After my test, I did not successfully reproduce your problem. After the update, the application can still be in the start menu. If possible, please provide more complete steps and your VS and OS versions.

Yeah, that's what I was saying, I can create a dummy application and it seems to work fine but whenever I'm trying it with my actual application, it doesn't keep it. This is using Visual Studio 2022 and the issue appears on both Windows 10 & 11

This could be some application-specific update action you have set, or some program code that is causing this issue. If possible, please provide the setup update about some settings and some code. If you just add a sample file in setup file, will your problem still occur?

The only Custom Action I have is installing Microsoft Edge WebView2 with each install/update.
My Application Folder installs the Publish Items from my application along with a 3rd party tool that I include with my install.
I have an "Auto Update" feature built in so it downloads the latest version from Github and then runs Msiexec.exe with the parameters being the msi file itself and then I specify the TARGETDIR and finish it off with /qb+.

You mentioned that you used a third-party tool, and maybe the problem is caused by this. It is recommended that you do not use a third-party tool to automatically update, but directly update Msiexec.exe locally in the form of a command line to see if the same problem still occurs.
